# Cannot open source file "GL/glew.h" when using CMake find_package()

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

as stated in the title, I am trying to add `glew.h` to my project built with CMake on Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10), and in doing so am experiencing an error thrown during the building stage `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory`.

I am including it in `engine.hpp` as such `#include <GL/glew.h>`

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(PROJECT GUI_Engine)

add_executable (${PROJECT} "./src/driver/main.cpp")

set(HEADER_FILES ./src/include)
set(DEC_FILES ./src/lib)
set(PKGPATH C:/dev/vcpkg/packages)

add_library(engine ${DEC_FILES}/engine.cpp ${HEADER_FILES}/engine.hpp)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PKGPATH}/sdl2_x64-windows)
find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PRIVATE engine SDL2::SDL2main)
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PKGPATH}/glew_x64-windows)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
```

Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize for my inexperience, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you use vcpkg, you should just use vcpkg's CMake integration and let it handle details. Your CMakeLists.txt should not contain any absolute path, it's supposed to be a file you share with other people alongside your source.*

That being said, the immediate issue at hand comes probably from this problem:

1. `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PRIVATE engine SDL2::SDL2main)`

   From which I guess your executable `#include`s some header from `engine` at some point. Probably `engine.hpp`, right?
2. `target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)`

   Makes Glew available to `engine` but privately. That is: only when building engine itself, not when building anything else (in particular, not when building the main executable).

From point 1., the dependency on Glew is exposed in the API of `engine`, so it is a public dependency. So you should mark it as `PUBLIC` in 2.:

```
target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC GLEW::GLEW)
```

Once CMake knows the dependency is exposed, it will also make Glew available to anything that uses `engine`.

Comment: Great answer, solved my problem exactly as asked for. Furthermore, as I am relatively new to vcpkg, I would be very appreciative if you could potentially attach some resources related to what you were saying about the CMake integration, or if you are able to, explain it yourself. Thanks again!

Comment: @Timesis I know it supports it and the official doc for CMake integration is [here](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/#cmake-toolchain-file), unfortunately I don't have first-hand experience with it so I will refrain from guiding you towards a wrong path. Hopefully the doc should be enough :)